# Does anyone know the name of the player who wore a customized face mask which looked like it was beaded?

Tags: american-football

What is the name of a defensive player in the NFL that wore a customized face mask that looked beaded?

The mask is yellow or gold, and black? I thought he was on the Bengals. He was a mostly known for clean but hard hits. I don't think he was particularly famous. I think he had long hair, braided from what I remember.

Answer (score 1):

The facemask was yellow and white, and the player was Sean Taylor.

[image: Yellow and white beaded facemask of Sean Taylor]